# How to compare instances of an class

Tags: python-3.x

With pygame I am trying to compare every instance of a class to each other with 2 for loops, but not itself. I am just not clear about how to exclude the first instance. help would be nice

edit: they are stored in a list

Comment: How are the instances stored?  In a list?

Comment: yes, in a list/array

Comment: Have you tried defining the `__eq__` method in your class?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get all possible combinations of a list’s elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464864/how-to-get-all-possible-combinations-of-a-list-s-elements)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `enumerate` function so that, with each instance, you get an index for it in the list.  Then, for your second loop, you avoid that index.

`enumerate` is a built-in function which takes an iterable object and provides you with a running counter in the for loop.

So,

```
for k, word in enumerate(['alfa','bravo','charlie']):
    print(k, word)
```

produces

```
0 alfa
1 bravo
2 charlie
```

```
for k, x in enumerate(list_of_instances):
    for y in (_ for j,_ in enumerate(list_of_instances) if j != k):
        do_a_thing()
```

EDIT:

You could also use slicing for the inner loop.  I.e.,

```
for y in list_of_instances[:k]:
    do_a_thing()
for y in list_of_instances[k:]:
    do_a_thing()
```

Comment: i'm still new to python, do u think you can explain this in a little bit more detail? like what do k and x represent in this context?